# Replace duplicates with new values in dataframe

Tags: dataframe, julia, dataframes.jl

I have a data frame with some repeat values in one of the columns:

`df = DataFrame(A=["a","a","b"])`

What I would like to do is replace all values with unique values and an incremental ordering if there are repeat values, like so:

`df = DataFrame(A=["a_1","a_2","b_1"])`

I know in R you can do this with `make.unique`, but is there an equivalent function in Julia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want exactly this output there is no ready function for this as far as I can tell, but you can do e.g.

```
julia> transform(groupby(df, :A), :A => (x -> string.(x, "_", 1:length(x))) => :A_unique)
3×2 DataFrame
 Row │ A       A_unique
     │ String  String
─────┼──────────────────
   1 │ a       a_1
   2 │ a       a_2
   3 │ b       b_1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way can be to generate a custom `uniquify` function for this purpose:

```
function uniquify(v)
    d = Dict{eltype(v),Int}()
    return map(v) do e
        d[e] = tmp = get(d, e, 0)+1
        return "$(e)_$tmp"
    end
end
```

Then,

```
julia> df = DataFrame(A=uniquify(["a","a","b"]))
3×1 DataFrame
 Row │ A      
     │ String 
─────┼────────
   1 │ a_1
   2 │ a_2
   3 │ b_1
```

EDIT: After a bit of squeezing and using `string` like Bogumil did in the other answer, this is the 1-line version of `uniquify` (works same as before):

```
uniquify(v; d = Dict{eltype(v),Int}()) =
  [string(e,'_',(d[e] = get(d,e,0)+1;)) for e in v]
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain to me what `get(d, e, 0)` does here? I think I understand that it's incrementing the value by 1 each time, but what is the 0 for exactly?

Comment: @august The `0` is the default value which is returned by `get` if it doesn't find `e`. This is important, as you want to start counting from 0 and then add 1.